# Getting module parameters in AJAX call using module id

Tags: joomla-3.x, ajax, custom-module

I have set up an AJAX call in my module which works fine.  I want to get the module parameters when I make the ajax call.  So I'm doing this

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_moduleName_display');
$params = new JRegistry($module->params);
```

This works fine except I have multiple mod_moduleName_display modules instances.  So it picks up the first module parameters not the one I want.

I can't find a way to get the module parameters using the module id.  I could pass them into the AJAX call or get them directly from the modules table but I'm hoping that there is a standard Joomla way of doing this that I've missed.

Update showing code for AJAX call:

sermon contains the module id - i.e. sermons.moduleToUse

```
function runAjax(page){

    page_no = page;
    moduleToUSe =  sermons.moduleToUse;
    sermons.start = page;
    var dataJSON = sermons;

    request = {
        'option' : 'com_ajax',
        'module' :  moduleToUSe,
        'parameters'  :  sermons,
        'format' : 'json'
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        type   : 'POST',
        data   : request,
        success: function (jsonObj) {
            jQuery("#container").html("");

            jsonArrayResponse =  jQuery.parseJSON(jsonObj["data"]);

            console.log(jsonArrayResponse);

        }
    });

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the Ajax call? You want to get the modules parameters, right?

Comment: I've added the Ajax call.  I pass an object with the module id which I want to use in the AJAX code to get the module params.  I can do this with a database call to the modules table but I hoped Joomla had a class so that the code would be more future proofed against changes

Comment: I have a solution but I'm not sure if this is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the ID, you can use `JModuleHelper::getModuleById()`.

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Helper.ModuleHelper.html#method_getModuleById

Comment: Thanks this is just what I wanted.  I'd already written code to get it from the _modules table but I really wanted to use the official joomla method.